# Argument exception in IsolatedStorageSettings in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, exception

In following code, I am getting `ArgumentException`. This code checks if a `key` is set in `IsolatedStorageSetting`. If it is not there , then it is created. At this point the exception is happening with message- `value does not fall within the expected range`. What wrong I am doing ?

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

         var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        if (settings.Contains("bm"))
        {
            string k = (string) settings["bm"];
            if (k == "1")
            {
                cb1.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cb1.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cb1.IsChecked=true;
            settings.Add("bm","1"); //exception occurs here
            settings.Save();
         }
}
```

Comment: Show us the text of exception

Comment: It's really strange, because I copied your code and everything works well.. without any exceptions

Answer (score 1):

As we can [see in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.add%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

`ArgumentException` occurs when

> key already exists in the dictionary.

So, I can see two problems:

- Somewhere in the parallel thread the key "bm" is beeng saved to settings.
- Keys are different. "ь" and "b" are different letters, but they looks similar.

Try to define one constant string:

```
private const string BM_KEY = "bm";
```

and use it every time you access to settings.

```
   if (settings.Contains(BM_KEY))
        {
            string k = (string) settings[BM_KEY];
            if (k == "1")
            {
                cb1.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cb1.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cb1.IsChecked=true;
            settings.Add(BM_KEY,"1"); //exception occurs here
            settings.Save();
        }
```

to be sure, that you use the same key every time.

Comment: As you said this exception happens if key already exists. Then why the `else` block is being executed ?

Answer (score 0):

Or try to remove the already existing key (example "lastBranoCalled") ;)

```
if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("lastBranoCalled"))
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("lastBranoCalled", this.Panorama.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                else MessageBox.Show("Error");
            else IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("lastBranoCalled", this.Panorama.SelectedIndex.ToString());
```